# Where do I find the expenses data in Sage?

Tags: financial, sage-line-50

I'm accessing sage 50 via the v16 ODBC driver, and I'm struggling to find the expenses data.

i.e. I'm shown an export which shows things like water bills, phone bills, salary etc, all going out from the company / main bank account

However I dont see this data in the audit_journal table, which from my limited knowledge is where I did expect to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use AUDIT_HEADER or AUDIT_SPLIT tables e.g. SELECT * FROM AUDIT_SPLIT

If you only want expenses then you should probably add a where clause for TYPE ="BP" OR TYPE="PI"

Audit Header is the group transaction header and audit split is the nominal code analysis.

Adam

Comment: Thanks. What is the audit_journal table then?  I have now found the data, just making sure I'm using the right thing!

Comment: Ignore the Audit journal table - its just a subset of the audit trail and only displays the journal entries e.g. JD and JC transactions